Using Polars df.write_delta() with localstack S3 storage
When trying to create a Delta Table using Polars df.write_delta(), I get an error when specifying endpoint_url that points to my aws localstack (when using boto3 with the same configuration, I'm able to list the buckets and keys).
Call:
df.write_delta(
        target=s3_path,
        mode="overwrite",
        overwrite_schema=True,
        storage_options={
            "AWS_REGION": "eu-central-1",
            "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "test",
            "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "test",
            "endpoint_url": "http://localhost:4566"
        }
    )

Error:
 File "/Users/x/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/batch-orZCP5o2-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/deltalake/table.py", line 415, in __init__
    self._table = RawDeltaTable(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: Generic S3 error: Error after 0 retries in 5.416µs, max_retries:10, retry_timeout:180s, source:builder error for url (http://localhost:4566/my_bucket/my_key/_delta_log/_last_checkpoint)

